# Write Query That Consider Date Interval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateinterval

I have a table that contains Transactions of Customers.
I should Find Customers That had have at least 2 transaction with amount>20000 in Three consecutive days each month.
For example , Today is 2022/03/12 , I should Gather Data Of Transactions From 2022/02/13 To 2022/03/12, Then check These Data and See If a Customer had at least 2 Transaction With Amount>=20000 in Three consecutive days.

For Example, Consider Below Table:

| Id | CustomerId | Transactiondate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 50000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022_02_01 | 20000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022_03_05 | 30000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022_03_07 | 40000 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022_03_07 | 20000 |
| 6 | 4 | 2022_03_07 | 30000 |
| 7 | 4 | 2022_03_07 | 30000 |

The Out Put Should be : CustomerId =3 and CustomerId=4

I write query that Find Customer For Special day , but i don't know how to find these customers in one month with out using loop.
the query for special day is:

```
With cte (select customerid, amount, TransactionDate,Dateadd(day,-2,TransactionDate) as PrevDate
From Transaction 
Where TransactionDate=2022-03-12)
Select CustomerId,Count(*)
From Cte 
Where 
TransactionDate>=Prevdate and TransactionDate<=TransactionDate
And Amount>=20000
Group By CustomerId
Having count(*)>=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are many options how to achieve this. 
I think that easies (from perfomance maybe not) is using `LAG` function:

```sql
WITH lagged_days AS (
SELECT
     ISNULL(LAG(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id),
LEAD(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id)) lagged_dt
    ,*
FROM Transaction
), valid_cust_base as (
SELECT
    * 
FROM lagged_days
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, lagged) = DATEPART(MONTH, Transactiondate) 
AND datediff(day, Transactiondate, lagged_dt) <= 3
AND Amount >= 20000
)
SELECT
CustomerID
FROM valid_cust_base 
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

First I have created lagged TransactionDate over customer (I assume that id is incremental). Then I have Selected only transactions within one month, with amount >= 20000 and where date difference between transaction is less then 4 days. Then just select customers who had more than 1 transaction.

In LAG First value is always missing per Customer missing, but you still need to be able say: 1st and 2nd transaction are within 3 days. Thats why I am replacing first NULL value with LEAD. It doesn't matter if you use:

```sql
ISNULL(LAG(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id),
LEAD(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id)) lagged_dt

OR

ISNULL(LEAD(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id),
LAG(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id)) lagged_dt
```

The main goal is to have for each transaction closest TransactionDate.

Comment: Thank You For Your Answer, It helps me a lot. I have a question, Why do you use lead? can't we use TransactionDate instead Of Lead Statement, I Imean we Write This: ISNULL(LAG(Transactiondate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY id),
Transactiondate) lagged_dt

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it helped dont forget accept it as answer.